# Installing phantomjs with node in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, phantomjs, devops

I'm trying to install the `phantomjs` executable in `/usr/local/bin` in a docker container, alongside node. I think I'm almost there, but I'm pretty new to docker and not well versed in installing binaries or working with Linux so struggling to work out where I'm going wrong.

This is my docker file:

```
FROM        node:6.4-onbuild

# Install phantomjs
WORKDIR     ~
RUN         apt-get install libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev \
            && apt-get install libfontconfig1 libfontconfig1-dev
RUN         export PHANTOM_JS="phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-i686" \
            && wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/$PHANTOM_JS.tar.bz2 \
            && tar xvjf $PHANTOM_JS.tar.bz2 \
            && mv $PHANTOM_JS /usr/local/share \
            && ln -sf /usr/local/share/$PHANTOM_JS/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin

WORKDIR     /usr/src/app
RUN         npm run build
EXPOSE      8080
CMD         ["node", "./bin/start.js"]
```

I've run bash on the container and there is definitely something called `phantomjs` in `/usr/local/bin` but I'm assuming that I've linked the wrong thing or it's an invalid executable. I'm thrown an error from my application telling me that there is no `phantomjs` executable in `/usr/local/bin`.

Can anyone give me a few pointers? Happy to provide more details if you post a comment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's an [existing image for this already on Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/wernight/phantomjs/) using the following Dockerfile:

```yaml
FROM debian:jessie 
  MAINTAINER Werner Beroux <werner@beroux.com> 
  # 1. Install runtime dependencies 
  # 2. Install official PhantomJS release 
  # 3. Clean up 

  RUN apt-get update \
      && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
          ca-certificates \
          bzip2 \
          libfontconfig \
      && apt-get clean \
      && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
  
  RUN apt-get update \
      && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
          curl \
      && mkdir /tmp/phantomjs \
      && curl -L https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 \
              | tar -xj --strip-components=1 -C /tmp/phantomjs \
      && cd /tmp/phantomjs \
      && mv bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin \
      && cd \
      && apt-get purge --auto-remove -y \
          curl \
      && apt-get clean \
      && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/lib/apt/lists/*
  
  # Run as non-root user 
  RUN useradd --system --uid 72379 -m --shell /usr/sbin/nologin phantomjs
  
  USER phantomjs 
  EXPOSE 8910 
  CMD ["/usr/local/bin/phantomjs"]
```

Comment: I tried that docker image first, didn't work for me. Maybe there was a problem using it with the node-onbuild docker image.

Comment: Difficult to help "didn't work" and "using it with the node-onbuild image" without a lot more detail.

Comment: Agreed, I'll re-run it and comment/edit my post with the results

Comment: I ended up just using two different containers and using a webdriver to control phantom. I'll accept your answer anyway since by all means the container above should have worked.

Answer (score 2):

We solved using the following docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

WORKDIR /opt/backend
RUN su -
RUN  apt-get update
RUN apt-get install sudo -y
RUN sudo apt install curl -y
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_17.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
RUN sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh
RUN sudo apt install nodejs -y 
RUN sudo apt-get install -y fontconfig
RUN sudo apt-get install -y libfontconfig

COPY . .
# Rference [https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs#linux-note][1]
RUN sudo npm set strict-ssl false
RUN sudo npm install 
RUN sudo npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt 
RUN sudo npm install -g html-pdf 

RUN sudo npm rebuild
RUN sudo npm run build

EXPOSE 3005
CMD npm run start:$env_Profile
```